# Can't vertically center text in a table cell

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website for a school project using HTML and CSS. In the header there is a table and I need a text (which is inside a cell) to be aligned on the vertical center and on the horizontal right.

This is the HTML code

```
<table id="intestazione">
........
    <tr>
        <td class="centerV"><h1>Text</h1></td>
        <td><img src="Logo.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and this is the CSS code

```
h1
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:50px;
    color:#009ED9;
    text-align:right;
}
.centerV
{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

but it doesn't work as I want, so I changed the CSS code into

```
h1
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:50px;
    color:#009ED9;

    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:right;
}
```

and the text is vertically centered, but not on the right (it is on the left). I've read that I can use `line-height` or a `padding` on the top, but in my opinion it is more clean and elegant to use `vertical-align` (tell me if I am wrong).

I tried also other code from suggestions on the web but I don't write it otherwise the question will be too long.

Comment: you want horizontal alignment to the right? because you are mentioning "right" and "left". vertical deals with "top", "buttom", "middle"

Comment: @repzero I need an horizontal alignment to the right and a vertical alignment on the "middle"

Comment: @mara6399 answer posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use :
 position : relative;
 right : value%;
 (or left:value%)
as you like ..

[check this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpLKLg)

```
<table id="intestazione" border="1">
<tr>
    <td class="centerV"><h1>Text</h1></td>
    <td><img src="http://www.sec4ever.com/home/images/misc/noavatar.gif"></td>


</tr>
```

```
h1{
font-family:Arial;
font-size:50px;
color:#009ED9;
display:table-cell;
padding:100px;
vertical-align:middle;
position:relative;
right:30%; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Take out `display:table-cell` from your `h1` headings and simply apply a `text-align:right` to your td elements.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #009ED9;
  text-align: right;
}

.centerV {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

tr {
  border: solid red;
}

td {
  border: solid green;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #009ED9;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: right;
}

h1 {
  border: solid red;
}

table {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table id="intestazione">
  ........
  <tr>
    <td class="centerV">
      <h1>Text</h1>
    </td>
    <td><img src="Logo.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `align="right"` in `td` by default content is vertically aligned in `td`.

```html
<table id="intestazione" width="100%" bgcolor="green">
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="middle" ><h1>Text</h1></td>
        <td><img src="Logo.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I had tried also this, but it didn't work... Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
h1 {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:50px;
    color:#085ED9;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    float: right;
}
```